# How continuity linked with dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity

I just practicing the multiple choice questions on analysis and saw this question and stuck there from hours.

**Question**: let $f:\mathbb{R} →\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. If $f(\mathbb{Q})⊆ \mathbb{N}$ then choose the correct of following.

a)$f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{N}$

b) $f(\mathbb{R}) ⊆ \mathbb{N}$ but $f$ need not be constant.

c) $f$ is unbounded.

d) $f$ is constant function.

I know, if $f$ is continuous map from connected subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then its image $f(M)$  must be connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$. But don't know, is there is any use of this result here? and How to discard wrong options?
Please help me.

Comment: You can discard the wrong options easily. $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{N}$ is absurd by the intermediate value theorem. If $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset \mathbb{N}$, then $f$ is constant, since any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is connected wrt $\mathbb{R}$'s topology iff it's a singleton (or empty...I forget if the empty set is connected or not, but images are always nonempty so that's irrelevant here). $f$ unbounded is absurd; $f(x) = 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Wow thank sir,That discards all three incorrect options. But please is there any way to prove $f$ is constant here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For irrational $q$, choose $(p_{n})$, $p_{n}$ rational such that $p_{n}\rightarrow q$. Since $f$ is continuous, then $f(p_{n})\rightarrow f(q)$. But $f(p_{n})$ are all natural numbers, the only convergent sequences in natural numbers are those constant sequences, so $f(q)$ is a natural number.

Now apply Intermediate Value Theorem to deduce that $f$ is actually a constant function:

For suppose $f$ is not constant, say, $f(a)=n$ and $f(b)=m$ with $a<b$, $n,m$ are natural numbers, pick a non-natural number $\eta$ in between $n,m$, then by Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ assumes the value $\eta$, but this is a contradiction since the range of $f$ is contained in all the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks sir. I think this is because of sequential criterion for continuous function?and $(p_n)→q exists , since for every real number there exists sequence of rationals converging to it ? But how to apply intermediate value theorem?

Comment: Yes, sequentially continuity plays the crucial role here. And the density of rational numbers in real.

Comment: Sir, how to use intermediate value theorem here? $f$ is continuous on $R$ so must have intermediate value property. But from this how to conclude f is constant?

Comment: Details added, you may take a look.

Comment: Thank sir. Got it.

Comment: It may be easier once you have that $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb N$ to use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is connected so $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected and the connected components of $\mathbb N$ are the singletons so $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yes, that is another approach, thanks.

Comment: @Driver8 ,how we get $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{N}$. Is this is because, given that $f(\mathbb{Q})⊆ \mathbb{N}$ and By answer of "user284331" it follows that, $f(\mathbb{Q^c})⊆ \mathbb{N})$ too and hence, $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{N}$. Is am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.